# Angular 2 resource not found main.js, serve content from build directory(which is pushed using gulp) instead of src/app path

Tags: visual-studio, angular, visual-studio-2015, gulp, systemjs

Trying to run Angular 2 app. Created empty project in Visual Studio 2015 in .NET 4.5.2 version and used `tsconfig.json` to compile all typescript into copy into build directory and I am referencing files from build directory lib folder. But its says *"404 main.js not found"*.

I need a way to serve the content from build directory instead of `src/app` directory where typescript files exist.

My `tsconfig.json` which compile ts files into js files in `build/app` directory:

```
  {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "build/app",
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false
      },
      "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "build"
      ]
   }
```

My `index.html`:

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>Angular 2 TypeScript Gulp QuickStart</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
        <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
        <script src="lib/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

        <script src="lib/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
        <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
        <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
        <script>
            System.import('app')
                    .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
        </script>

    </head>

    <!-- 3. Display the application -->
    <body>
        <app>Loading...</app>
    </body>

</html>
```

But here in `index.html` it is trying to look for `main.js` file in path `src`, but `main.js` is compiled and stored in `build/app` directory. How do I reference it in my code?

My `systemjs.config.js`:

```
(function (global) {

    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app': 'app',
        'rxjs': 'lib/rxjs',
        '@angular': 'lib/@angular'
    };

    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
    };

    var packageNames = [
        '@angular/common',
        '@angular/compiler',
        '@angular/core',
        '@angular/http',
        '@angular/platform-browser',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
        '@angular/router',
        '@angular/router-deprecated',
        '@angular/testing',
        '@angular/upgrade'
    ];

    // add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    packageNames.forEach(function (pkgName) {
        packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    });

    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    };

    // filterSystemConfig - index.html's chance to modify config before we register it.
    if (global.filterSystemConfig) {
        global.filterSystemConfig(config);
    }

    System.config(config);

})(this);
```

My `Gulp.js` file:

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const del = require("del");
const tsc = require("gulp-typescript");
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const tsProject = tsc.createProject("tsconfig.json");
const tslint = require('gulp-tslint');


/**
 * Remove build directory.
 */
gulp.task('clean', (cb) => {
    return del(["build"], cb);
});

/**
 * Compile TypeScript sources and create sourcemaps in build directory.
 */
gulp.task("compile", () => {
    var tsResult = gulp.src("src/**/*.ts")
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(tsc(tsProject));
    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("build"));
});

/**
 * Copy all resources that are not TypeScript files into build directory.
 */
gulp.task("resources", () => {
    return gulp.src(["src/**/*", "!**/*.ts"])
        .pipe(gulp.dest("build"))
});

/**
 * Copy all required libraries into build directory.
 */
gulp.task("libs", () => {
    return gulp.src([
            'core-js/client/shim.min.js',
            'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
            'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
            'reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
            'rxjs/**',
            'zone.js/dist/**',
            '@angular/**'
    ], { cwd: "node_modules/**" }) /* Glob required here. */
        .pipe(gulp.dest("build/lib"));
});

/**
 * Build the project.
 */
gulp.task("build", ['compile', 'resources', 'libs'], () => {
    console.log("Building the project ...")
});
```

I found solution using lite-server I mean run code in Visual Studio code:
In `bs-config.json` file:

```
{
  "port": 8000,
  "files": [
    "build/**/*.{html,htm,css,js}"
  ],
  "server": {
    "baseDir": "build"
  }
}
```

this would solve issue in VS code. But I want to redirect path to build directory for visual studio 2015 project.

Anyone know how to do browserSync in Visual studio 2015 so that i can put above code in place where it will serve contents from build directory instead of files from `src/app`.

Here are the errors I get:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) http://localhost:53149/src/lib/core-js/client/shim.min.js
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) http://localhost:53149/src/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.js
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) http://localhost:53149/src/lib/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) http://localhost:53149/src/lib/core-js/client/shim.min.js
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) http://localhost:53149/src/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.js
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) http://localhost:53149/src/lib/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) http://localhost:53149/src/lib/systemjs/dist/system.src.js
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) systemjs.config.js:44 Uncaught ReferenceError: System is
>   not defined       index.html:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not
>   defined

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add `build/app` to the package defintion in `systemjs.config.js` like:

```
var packages = {
    'app': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'build/app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }

};
```

(Sorry, can't comment to ask.. )

Comment: Thank you, I found solution i need to set path in the map:  var map = {
        'app': '../build/app',
        'rxjs': '../build/lib/rxjs',
        '@angular': '../build/lib/@angular'
    };